# How can I change the frame of the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistatusbar

I've tried using this to get the frame of the status bar:

```
var statusBarWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")
```

however, when I try to change the frame, it says the value is immutable:

```
statusBarWindow?.frame = CGRect(x: -oldViewFrame, y: statusBarWindow.frame.origin.y, width: statusBarWindow.frame.size.width, height: statusBarWindow.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: I need to change the frame of the status bar and [this](https://github.com/ndesai/InstagramStatusBarTest/blob/master/InstagramStatusBarTest/ViewController.m) is the only way I've found online, and it gives me an immutable object. Where can I access the mutable status bar frame?

Comment: The frame rectangle defining the area of the status bar. (read-only) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarFrame

Comment: @LeoDabus so that implies that status bar frames can't be manipulated in swift, but they can in Obj-c?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarFrame OBJ-C read-only also

Comment: in the slack iOS app, they change the y position of the status bar. Do you know how they did it?

Comment: They did not change its size they are only using the same tint color for the navigation bar

Comment: that's not correct at all, there is an animation shifting it up and down depending on if the side bar is open or not. So can you please help me find a solution on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna give you an answer based on the comments you've written about your intention with this question.

---

**Solution**

You can get the statusbar to disappear when opening the sidebar (similar to the Slack app) by overriding the method `prefersStatusBarHidden` from `UIViewController` for the sidebar. It should be something like the following:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

You can also modify the appearance of this with the two methods: `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation`

---

**Example**

I've made a simple project to illustrate this. It is possible to implement a sidebar in many different ways, so instead I've based this example on a popover. Your implementation will depend on how you've implemented the sidebar.

I've made a simple storyboard with two `UIViewController` and a `UIButton` in each. When clicking on the first `UIButton`, then it will trigger a segue with the type `Present As Popover` that will show the second controller.

The first `UIViewController` has no code in it (everything is done in the storyboard), but the second `UIViewController` has the code for hiding the status bar.

I've attached a screenshot of the storyboard and the code for the second `UIViewController` below.

```
//
//  PopController.swift
//  SidebarHideStatus
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 31/01/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class PopController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Storyboard actions

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Status bar

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard of the example project, highlighting the segue attached to the <code>UIButton</code>]

---

**UPDATE 1**: OP uses a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController` for the sidebar.

First of all, I would recommend that you factorize your sidebar into a separate `UIViewController` since it will make it much more reusable in the future, but that's a completely different discussion which could go on for days!

In order to hide the status bar, then you still need to make use of the callback method I highlighted before, but you simply gotta call the method `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in order to manually update it.

I've updated the initial `UIViewController` with the following code and deleted the segue in order to demonstrate this approach.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SidebarHideStatus
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 31/01/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var isSidebarShown = false

    // MARK: - Storyboard outlets

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        isSidebarShown = !isSidebarShown
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    // MARK: - Status bar

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return isSidebarShown
    }

    override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
        // NOTE: This method has no effect now when
        // using the method setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        return .Slide
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you but, i don't think i can implement this within my project because I used a UIView to hold the side bar. I used UIViewAnimation to move the view tied to the current VC and just shifted the sidebar over by the amount I set the original view. So in essence, i'm not popping over any other VC's. So if with one VC, how can I refresh the view in order to re-trigger the prefersstatusbarhidden function?

Comment: Thank you @Kumuluzz! This solved the problem. I have a question for you though: I subclassed UIView in order to create the sidebar, so it's still reusable, not because it's the best, but it was the only solution I could come up with. What advantages would I have by creating a UIVC over what I did? I definitely want to become a better programmer, so if you can articulate it with as much detail as possible, I would be very grateful!